# Example of sequence of integrable functions that converges to a not integrable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can you suggest an example of a sequence of functions $f_n: [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- $f_n$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ $\forall n$
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x) $, $\forall x \in [a,b]$, with $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is **not** integrable on $[a,b]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider for example
$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x} I\{x > \tfrac{1}{n}\}$$
on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you specify what is meant by $I\{ x>1/n \} $?

Comment: That's an indicator function.

Comment: May I ask what is the definition of $I\{x> 1/n\}$  in this  particular case?

Comment: It'a function whose value is $1$ if $x > \frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ else.